# \gtab [songs package] using macro variable as second parameter

Tags: macros, songs

`\gtabs` prints a guitar chord based on two parameters

```
\gtab{chord name}{guitar frets and strings}
```

The second parameter is not accepting another macrovariable defined with `\def` or `\gdef`.  See the following example as well as the picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{songs}

\newcommand{\hpvarB}[2]{
    \gtab{#1}{#2} 

}
\begin{document}
    The ``A'' chord prints as: \gtab{A}{002220}
    \\
    \def\hpvarA{A}{002220}
    However the chord graph does not print with macro variable as second parameter\par
    \gtab{A}{\hpvarA} 
    \\
    Only the chordname "A" is printed.  Any hints?\par 
    Macro hpvarB works!\hpvarB{B}{024442} But with hpvarA as \hpvarB{A}{\hpvarA} it does not

\end{document}
```

If you do not have the package `songs` installed this could give a hint on the `\gtab` macro definition for any suggestion you have

```
\newcommand\gtab{\SB@begincname\SB@gtab}
\newcommand*\SB@gtab[1]{%
    \SB@endcname%
    \begingroup%
    \catcode`:12\relax%
    \SB@@gtab{#1}%
}
\newcommand*\SB@@gtab[2]{%
    \endgroup%
    \ifnum\SB@transposefactor=\z@%
    \SB@@@gtab{#1}{#2}%
    \else%
    \begingroup%
    \let\gtab\SB@@@gtab%
    \gtabtrans{#1}{#2}%
    \endgroup%
    \fi%
}
```

[image]

Comment: `\def\hpvarA{A}{002220}` defines `\hpvarA` to have A and prints `002220` after that. It is not what you want, here

Comment: As it stands, the `\hpvarB` macro will produce spurious spaces

Answer (score 2):

`\def\hpvarA{A}{002220}` defines `\hpvarA` to have the expansion `{A}` and the text `002220` is printed right after the definition, so this is not 'glued' together to form the right input for `\gtab`.

Either define `\hpvarA` to expand to `002220` only and this requires a lot of `\expandafter` statements in `\hpvarB` or define it as

`\def\hpvarA{{A}{002220}}`  (note the braces inside) and

```
\newcommand{\hpvarC}[1]{%
\expandafter\gtab#1%
}
```

and either say `\expandafter\gtab\hpvarA` or just `\hpvarC{\hpvarA}`

In either case, the `\hpvarA` content must be expanded first before it can be fed to `\gtab`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{songs}

\newcommand{\hpvarB}[2]{%
  \expandafter\gtab\expandafter{\expandafter#1\expandafter}\expandafter{#2}% 
}

\newcommand\hpvarC[1]{%
  \expandafter\gtab#1%
}

\begin{document}
    The ``A'' chord prints as: \gtab{A}{002220}

    \def\hpvarA{{A}{002220}}
    \def\hpvarAother{002220}
    However the chord graph does not print with macro variable as second parameter\par
    \expandafter\gtab\hpvarA


    Only the chordname "A" is printed.  Any hints?\par 
    Macro hpvarB works!\hpvarB{B}{024442} But with hpvarA as \hpvarB{A}{\hpvarAother} it does not

    \hpvarC{\hpvarA}
```

\end{document}

[image]

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  I made a simple mistake in trying to recreate an example of my real issue now with pgfkeys as posted here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355411/gtab-songs-package-using-pgfkeys-property-as-second-parameter

Answer (score 2):

1. As already mentioned by others, the macro `\hpvarB` contains spaces that will get tokenized as space tokens and thus might result in undesired horizontal space if processed in horizontal mode or in restricted horizontal mode.
2. The line `\def\hpvarA{A}{002220}` does the following: It defines the macro `\hpvarA` to expand to `A` and it prints the sequence `002220` which is nested inside a local scope.
   Therefore `\gtab{A}{\hpvarA}` is: `\gtab{A}{<something that expands to 'A'>}`.
   You need the arguments of `\gtab` to be fully expanded to the correct values before having LaTeX carry out `\gtab`.

You can apply the following techniques:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{songs}

\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%

\newcommand\OneLevelExpandSecondFirst[2]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{#2}{ #1}%
}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand\TotalExpandSecondFirst[2]{%
   \begingroup
   \protected@edef\mytempa{{#2}}%
   \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\mytempa{\endgroup#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\hpvarB[2]{\gtab{#1}{#2}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\hpvarC[2]{\TotalExpandSecondFirst{\expandafter\gtab\@firstofone}{{#1}{#2}}}%
\makeatother

%-<Layout of example>----------------------------
\newcommand\horizmargins{2cm}%
\newcommand\vertmargins{2cm}%
\setlength\textwidth\paperwidth
\addtolength\textwidth{-\horizmargins}%
\addtolength\textwidth{-\horizmargins}%
\setlength\oddsidemargin{\horizmargins}%
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1in}%
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-\hoffset}%
\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}%
\setlength\marginparwidth{\horizmargins}%
\addtolength\marginparwidth{-2\marginparsep}%
\setlength\columnseprule{\fboxrule}%
\setlength\headheight{0ex}%
\setlength\headsep{0ex}%
\setlength\footnotesep{\vertmargins}%
\setlength\footnotesep{.666\footnotesep}%
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight}
\addtolength\textheight{-\vertmargins}%
\addtolength\textheight{-\vertmargins}%
\setlength\topmargin{\vertmargins}%
\addtolength\topmargin{-1in}%
\addtolength\topmargin{-\voffset}%
\addtolength\topmargin{-\topskip}%
\addtolength\topmargin{\ht\strutbox}%
\pagestyle{empty}%
\setlength\parindent{0ex}%
\twocolumn
%------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
\gtab{B}{024442}

\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\gtab{B}{024442}

\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim}
\hpvarB{B}{024442}

\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\hpvarB{B}{024442}

\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim}
\gtab{A}{002220}

\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\gtab{A}{002220}

\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim}
\hpvarB{A}{002220}

\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\hpvarB{A}{002220}

\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim}
\def\hpvarA{{A}{002220}}%
\expandafter\gtab\hpvarA
\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\def\hpvarA{{A}{002220}}%
\expandafter\gtab\hpvarA

\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim}
\def\hpvarA{{A}{002220}}%
\expandafter\hpvarB\hpvarA
\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\def\hpvarA{{A}{002220}}%
\expandafter\hpvarB\hpvarA

\newpage

\begin{verbatim}
\def\hpvarA{002220}%
\OneLevelExpandSecondFirst{\gtab{A}}{\hpvarA}
\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\def\hpvarA{002220}%
\OneLevelExpandSecondFirst{\gtab{A}}{\hpvarA}

\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim}
\def\hpvarA{002220}%
\TotalExpandSecondFirst{\gtab{A}}{\hpvarA}
\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\def\hpvarA{002220}%
\TotalExpandSecondFirst{\gtab{A}}{\hpvarA}

\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim}
\def\hpvarA{002220}%
\OneLevelExpandSecondFirst{\hpvarB{A}}{\hpvarA}
\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\def\hpvarA{002220}%
\OneLevelExpandSecondFirst{\hpvarB{A}}{\hpvarA}

\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim}
\def\hpvarA{002220}%
\TotalExpandSecondFirst{\hpvarB{A}}{\hpvarA}
\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\def\hpvarA{002220}%
\TotalExpandSecondFirst{\hpvarB{A}}{\hpvarA}

\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim}
\hpvarC{A}{002220}

\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\hpvarC{A}{002220}

\hrulefill

\begin{verbatim}
\def\hpvarX{A}%
\def\hpvarA{002220}%
\hpvarC{\hpvarX}{\hpvarA}
\end{verbatim}
yields:\\
\def\hpvarX{A}%
\def\hpvarA{002220}%
\hpvarC{\hpvarX}{\hpvarA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful to understand my mistake in trying to recreate the real issue I have with pgfkeys (posted now at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355411/gtab-songs-package-using-pgfkeys-property-as-second-parameter)

Comment: Your explanation here helped me to solve the issue with pgfkeys  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355411/gtab-songs-package-using-pgfkeys-property-as-second-parameter/356096#356096